# Display image as a byte array: doesn't work

Tags: android, byte

My issue is: I have a byte array which must be display with ImageView. This is my code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

   ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.show_image);
   byte[] arrayBytes = ...; // It's initialized

   BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
   options.inSample = 4;
   imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(arrayBytes, 0, arrayBytes.length,     options));
}
```

The code of activity_main.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/show_image"
        android:contentDescription="@string/Imagen"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

But it doesn't work: no image has been displayed! What's I'm doing wrong?

To get byte array[], I read a double[][] array 2D from a file. To get byte value for each element of the matrix I used:

```
byte[] byteArray = new byte[SIZE];
int k = 0;

for(...i) {
    for(...j) {
        byteArray[k] = Double.valueOf(matrix[i][j]).byteValue();
        k++;
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using one byte for each pixel? The default format is ARGB_8888 which needs four bytes per pixel.

Comment: Yes, I'm using one byte for each pixel. How to do this transformation?